# Making a grey block test card pattern

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I need to make the following and i am unsure on what to do in order to archive this.

i need it to look like this:

[image: Image of what i need]

This is what i have done so far:

```
     float tempHeight = height * 0.20f;
     float tempWidth = width * 0.20f;
     float increase = 0;
     float colour = 0.20f;
     float temp = 0;
     tempHeight = tempHeight / 3;

for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {            
             gl2.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
               gl2.glColor3f(colour, colour, colour);    // Set the current drawing color 
               gl2.glVertex3f(0, height * 0.20f + temp, 0.0f);  // Top Left
               gl2.glVertex3f(width * 0.20f , height * 0.20f + temp, 0.0f);   // Top Right
               gl2.glVertex3f(width * 0.20f , temp, 0.0f);  // Bottom Right
               gl2.glVertex3f(0, temp, 0.0f); // Bottom Left
           gl2.glEnd();


         for(int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {

                 gl2.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
                    gl2.glColor3f(colour,colour,colour);

                if (a == 0 || a == 2 || a == 3) {
                    gl2.glColor3f(1f, 0f, 0f);
                }   
              gl2.glVertex3f(tempWidth, tempHeight + increase, 0.0f);  // Top Left
               gl2.glVertex3f(tempWidth * 2 ,  tempHeight + increase, 0.0f);   // Top Right
               gl2.glVertex3f(tempWidth * 2 , tempHeight * a , 0.0f);  // Bottom Right
               gl2.glVertex3f(tempWidth, tempHeight * a , 0.0f); // Bottom Left
           gl2.glEnd();
             }            
            increase = tempHeight;              
            colour = colour + 0.20f;
        //    tempWidth = tempWidth + width * 0.20f;
            temp = temp + height * 0.20f; 
          //  tempHeight = tempHeight + height * 0.20f;
           for(int b = 0; b < 5; b++) {

           }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should avoid [deprecated OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL). If you want you can start from an hello triangle of [mine](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/helloTriangle) and experiment on that.

Second, what you are asking is relative easy, you have to declare your vertex geometry that matches that shape you want, that is:

[image]

Then, you render it five times (in this example) and each time you need to:

- change the position by uploading a matrix that is going to multiply each vertex of your geometry
- set a different color that will be used by your fragment shader to shade the geometry

If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask